# Email Address and Phone in Text field in Salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: community, sfmc-business-unit, marketing-cloud

I am receiving a file in the Data Extension, where the value field contains the email address and phone information in the text data type.
Could someone guide me on how i can pull the Email and phone values into separate fields from the value field of text data type.

Comment: please share an example of the pattern the data has (anonymized). This cannot be answered in a meaningful way without seeing an example I think.

Comment: Value field contains - abc@gmail.com, +1898754234
Now i want to know a way through which i can separate email address and phone number in separate fields.

Comment: is the email address and phone number is in the single text field and comma separated? Do you want to split them and populate them in to the respective fields into the data extension?

Comment: @RashmiBudakoti Thats right!

Answer (score 0):

I personally am a fan of the "replace unwanted stuff with nothing" approach.
You could do this with two simple SQL queries using PATINDEX.

Here are some examples for a similar usecase:

split email addresses into the part "to the left of the @" / "to the right of the @"

this you can easily adapt to your field and "," instead of "@".

```
/* remove everything right of the @ */
SELECT Replace(EmailAddress,
RIGHT(EmailAddress,LEN(EmailAddress) - LEN(RIGHT(EmailAddress,(PATINDEX('%@%',EmailAddress))))),
'') 
FROM _Subscribers
```

```
/* remove everything left of the @ */
SELECT Replace(EmailAddress,
LEFT(EmailAddress,(PATINDEX('%@%',EmailAddress) - 1)),
'') 
FROM _Subscribers
```

I would suggest to first write the results into text fields to test the general approach. Once you use emailAddress / Phone data types in the target Data Extension(s), there will be field constraints that could break your queries because of the data contained.

example:
Suppose there is a faulty email address ("spam@spam") in your data, then this might cause errors trying to populate an EmailAddress field because that is not conforming to the "valid email" pattern, so to speak. First writing into plain text fields will not trigger this validation and will help you isolate errors.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thank you for the response. The query worked for me. But i am getting a (,) and a space after email address in the email address field and a space and (,) after phone number . To populate the data into phone i had to change the data type to text since it was not accepting (,) in the phone data type.

Comment: that is what I meant. If you want to USE phone as intended (write an SMS to the value of the field), you will have to put it into a phone field. then you have to work with the constraints. If your input data doesn't match, solve that problem first. Step one could be to also Replace "," with nothing in the same pattern. But phone and email validation can get pretty complex.

Answer (score 0):

Although @JonasLamberty answer is solid, I wanted to share an alternative solution as well using PARSENAME() in SQL.

**[PARSENAME()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** will take the input and divide it into sections using `.` as the delimiter.

```
PARSENAME('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890',1)
```

PARSENAME() works from right to left though, so to get the correct order, you will need to REVERSE() it.

```
PARSENAME(REVERSE('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890'),1)
```

Now, this is not going to really help your situation as you are using `,` as the delimiter you want. So you will need to utilize a REPLACE() to change `,` to `.`.

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890'), ',','.'),1)
```

The issue you then run into is that your string contains a period in it already. This means that it will read the `.` in `.com` as a delimiter and split that too. To get around that, you just need another replace. What I usually do is use a special char that you know is very unlikely to ever be used inside those strings.

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890'),'.','~'), ',','.'),1)
```

You then have to do one more REPLACE() to change the `.` back from your special char (`~`):

```
REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890'),'.','~'), ',','.'),1),'~','.')
```

You then have to do one more REVERSE() to output accordingly and then you are all set:

```
REVERSE(REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE('abc@gmail.com, +1234567890'),'.','~'), ',','.'),1),'~','.'))
```

Which will output:

```
abc@gmail.com
```

So for example, you could use the following assuming `myField` is `abc@gmail.com, +1234567890`:

```sql
SELECT 
REPLACE(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(myField),'.','~'), ',', '.'), 1)),'~','.') AS Email
, REPLACE(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(myField),'.','~'), ',', '.'), 2)),'~','.') AS Phone
FROM [myDE]
```

which would output:

```
Email         | Phone
abc@gmail.com | +1234567890
```

This is something I would only use on smaller delimited strings (no more than 4 segments) and where no part of the string exceeds 256 bytes. But this could be an option that is a bit more inline with modern SQL best practices for handling this type of need within those constraints.

For any use cases that fall outside the constraints of PARSENAME() I would also recommend the XML approach I laid out **[here](https://gortonington.com/retrieving-specific-values-from-a-delimited-string-inside-sfmc-sql/)**.